# Copy selected data from one sheet and paste to other sheet on selected range if it fulfill the criteria

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have two sheets say (Sheet1)=Sheets("Jan") and sheet2=Sheets("Feb")
I want to copy only that data from range b5:b81 from sheets ("Jan") to sheets("Feb") if it meets the condition in range AN5:AN81.

I am using this code but not working

```
Sub CopyRows()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim Cl As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim RowUpdCrnt As Long

    Set Rng = Sheets("Jan").UsedRange  'the range to search ie the used range
    Set Rng2 = Sheets("Jan").Range("B")
    str = "WRK." 'string to look for

    Sheets("Feb").Range("B5:B81").Value = ""

    RowUpdCrnt = 5

    ' In my test data, the "Yes"s are in column AN.  This For-Each only selects column AN.
    ' I assume all your "Yes"s are in a single column.  Replace "B" by the appropriate
    ' column letter for your data.

    For Each Cl In Rng.Columns("AN").Rows
        If Cl.Text = str Then
            'if the cell contains the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet 2 &  delete the row
            Cl.cell(2, 5).Copy Sheets("Feb").Cells(RowUpdCrnt, 1)
            RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
        End If
    Next Cl
End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't like others editing your posts to improve code formatting, consider reading [the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) — your first lines of code are distorted and the rest is misindented.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: And, by the way, not only your code is not highlighted properly because you have put wrong tag (*copy* is not relevant to this question, while *excel-vba* is), that also stands in the way between you and your intended audience — question is not getting views of the people interested in Excel and VBA.